# Call an object method from a string

Tags: lua

I have a main loop in my lua script, and i am including 2 objects like this:

```
local Menu = require("menu")
local InputHandler = require("inputhandler")
```

Here are the scripts for each object:

menu.lua

```
Menu = {
  Active = false,
  Initialise = function(self)
  end,
  ToggleMenu = function(self)
    self.Active = not self.Active
    print(self.Active)
  end
}
return Menu
```

and inputhandler.lua

```
InputHandler = {
  KeyBinds = {
    q = { scancode = 16, bind = "q", action = "Menu:ToggleMenu" }
  },
  RunKeyAction = function (self, key)
    for k, v in pairs(self.KeyBinds) do
      if (v.bind == key) then
        _G[v.action]()
      end
    end
  end
}
return InputHandler
```

Basically I am trying to map keyboard keys to various functions within my script, so when someone presses "Q", it will run the method associated with that key.

So if I do something like this:

```
InputHandler:RunKeyAction("q")
```

It will run this method:

```
Menu:ToggleMenu()
```

When I run this script as it is now, I get this error:

```
lua: ./classes//inputhandler.lua:8: attempt to call field '?' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ./classes//inputhandler.lua:8: in function 'RunKeyAction'
    [string "<eval>"]:20: in main chunk
```

Can anyone please tell me that correct way of doing this?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
q = { scancode = 16, bind = "q", action = Menu.ToggleMenu }
```

and

```
v:action()
```

Comment: hello lhf, thanks a lot for your reply, i get this error when i try it that way: inputhandler.lua:4: attempt to index global 'Menu' (a nil value)

Comment: @Aaranihlus but you need to remember that state `Active` written in table `q.Active` instead `Menu.Active` ;-)